# SQL Server 2008 SSRS Total/Combine values from two tables to output into a dataset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report that needs to switch between three different datasets i.e. order types = Consumable, Service and Total.

I have two queries one for Consumable and one for Service as shown below.  I tried putting a union between them but it doesn't seem to be totalling the results i.e. adding the two together.  How can I do this?

```
SELECT COUNT(orderheader.orderid)             AS [Consumable Order Amount], 
       CONVERT(DATE, orderheader.datecreated) AS [Date], 
       CASE 
         WHEN orderheader.webref = '' THEN 'Call Centre' 
         ELSE 'Web' 
       END                                    AS [Order Type] 
FROM   orderheader 
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, orderheader.datecreated) >= '21 February 2011' 
       AND CONVERT(DATE, orderheader.datecreated) <= '20 March 2011' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, orderheader.datecreated), 
          CASE 
            WHEN orderheader.webref = '' THEN 'Call Centre' 
            ELSE 'Web' 
          END 

SELECT COUNT(serviceid)           AS [Service Order Amount], 
       CONVERT(DATE, datecreated) AS [Date], 
       CASE 
         WHEN serviceorder.webref = '' THEN 'Call Centre' 
         ELSE 'Web' 
       END                        AS SOURCE 
FROM   serviceorder 
WHERE  ( CONVERT(DATE, datecreated) >= '21 February 2011' ) 
       AND ( CONVERT(DATE, datecreated) <= '20 March 2011' ) 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, datecreated), 
          CASE 
            WHEN serviceorder.webref = '' THEN 'Call Centre' 
            ELSE 'Web' 
          END 
ORDER  BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this for the combined dataset?

```
;WITH Combined AS
(
    SELECT orderid AS id,
        datecreated as [datecreated],
        webref as [webref]
    FROM orderheader
    UNION ALL
    SELECT serviceid AS id,
        datecreated as [datecreated],
        webref as [webref]
    FROM serviceorder
)
SELECT COUNT(id) AS [Service Order Amount], 
       CONVERT(DATE, datecreated) AS [Date], 
       CASE 
         WHEN webref = '' THEN 'Call Centre' 
         ELSE 'Web' 
       END AS SOURCE 
FROM   Combined 
WHERE  ( CONVERT(DATE, datecreated) >= '21 February 2011' ) 
       AND ( CONVERT(DATE, datecreated) <= '20 March 2011' ) 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, datecreated), 
          CASE 
            WHEN webref = '' THEN 'Call Centre' 
            ELSE 'Web' 
          END 
ORDER  BY [Date]
```

Comment: This looks good... will I get dupes tho with UNION ALL?  Will that throw the totals off?

Comment: Not sure... Try it out to see if it's what you're looking for. A couple points to help: (1) There will only be one row per source and date in the results, (2) UNION ALL counts each row even if orderid matches a particular serviceid. (3) Change UNION ALL To UNION to eliminate duplicates (i.e. when orderid and serviceid happen to match and you only want to count that number once)

Comment: I think this will resolve my issue thanks... Now i have to create a new question to figure out how i'm going to combine 3 different queries into one report!